# Stopping clip with clip.close()

Tags: java, audio, clip

I have a button in my program where i could enable or disable the sound. I tried with this code but i can only start the clip. Do you have any suggestions?

```
if (control == view.btnSound) {
        try {
            URL url = this.getClass().getResource("test.wav");
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);

            final Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

            clip.open(audioIn);

            if (view.btnSound.isSelected()) {

                clip.start();
                view.btnSound.setText("Sound ein");


                //clip.loop(clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            }

            else  {

                    clip.stop();



                view.btnSound.setText("Sound aus");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You create a new instance of `Clip` each time the button is clicked, but you really only want to create a new instance when you want to start playing.  Make `clip` an instance field of the class, check to see if it's `null`, when it is (and the button is selected), create a new instance of `clip` and start it playing, otherwise, when the button is not selected and `clip` is not `null`, use `stop`

Comment: I tried it before, but maybe i did something wrong...
After your comment i tried again and it worked! 
THX!! :)